# Sequence of type-operators and kind requirements

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

Toying around with `TypeOperators` I've tried implementing `$` and `.` so I can rid my program of any parentheses (no offence to any beautiful Lispers out there). In doing so I've isomorphically copied the definitions. First I attempted only using `$` because you shouldn't need `.` with its beefy power.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
type f $ a = f a

f :: Int -> IO $ Either String Int
f n = undefined
```

Great. This compiles and I'm content.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
type f $ a = f a

f :: Int -> IO $ Maybe $ Either String Int
f n = undefined
```

This should work right?

```
TyCo.hs:4:18:
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Maybe’
    The second argument of ‘$’ should have kind ‘*’,
      but ‘Maybe’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    In the type signature for ‘f’:
      f :: Int -> (IO $ Maybe) $ Either String Int
```

Apparently not.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
type f $ a = f a
type (f * g) a = f (g a)

f :: Int -> IO * Maybe $ Either String Int
f n = undefined
```

With blind hope, I try.

```
TyCo.hs:5:6:
    Type synonym ‘*’ should have 3 arguments, but has been given 2
    In the type signature for ‘f’:
      f :: Int -> (IO * Maybe) $ Either String In
```

In my ignorant stupor I raise the question: `WHY` doesn't it work?

Comment: For your first example, it looks like the associativity of `$` is wrong. I suppose `$` at the value level and `$` at the type level are considered different identifiers, and we haven't declared a precedence or associativity for the latter.  I don't know how to, or if there is a way.  At least play with `infixr` a bit...

Comment: You should also enable `PolyKinds` and/or `LiberalTypeSynonyms` if you expect these shortcuts to be generally useful.

Comment: @luqui's comments are both on the right track.  You can fix the first version with `infixr 0 $` and the second version with `LiberalTypeSynonyms`.

Comment: Note however that `$` and `.` are not sufficient to get rid of *all* parentheses in general.

Comment: I've solved both issues now thanks to you guys. Don't forget to post an answer so you can claim your e-points and sate the system.

Comment: I was waiting for @luqui to get the first chance to it, but he hasn't posted anything on SO since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue has to do with the fixity of `$`, you can see the signs in the error message by paying attention to where the parentheses are placed. `(IO $ Maybe)` is a partially applied type-synonym, resulting in the error. You can't partially apply type-synonyms because it needs to compare them and that is equivalent to comparing functions.

`LiberalTypeSynonyms` just makes GHC unwrap type-synonyms before it does the type-checking, i.e. `(IO * Maybe) $ Either String Int` becomes `(IO (Maybe (Either String Int)))` and *then* it type-checks. This means `*` is no longer partially applied, and the program compiles.